# O que é ataque CSRF e quais danos ele pode causar?

Tags: segurança, csrf

Estou vendo algumas pessoas mencionando os tais ataques **CSRF** aqui no Stack Overflow.

O que eu gostaria de saber é:

- O que é um ataque **CSRF**?
- Como ele é feito?
- Quais danos ele pode causar?
- Como eu posso evitar ataques CSRF?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### O que um ataque CSRF?

É um tipo de ataque para danificar ou roubar dados de um usuário em um serviço web. Geralmente um site, widget ou aplicativo mal intencionado aproveita-se do usuário estar logado em algum serviço web e executa ações nesse serviço.

[CSRF no OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)

### Como ele é feito? Quais danos ele pode causar?

**XSS**: Digamos que você tem um facebook e, como quase todo mundo, seu navegador está sempre logado no facebook. Você entra num site malicioso que contém um iframe apontando para o facebook. Quando você terminar de carregar a página, esse site executa um javascript que preenche o status do facebook para "sou n00b" e aperta enviar. (Esse cenário atualmente é "bloqueado" pelos navegadores web)

**CSRF**: Digamos que você tem uma conta no banco do Panama, e loga no seu web banking. Esse web banking é feito em web 1.0, onde cada link ou formulário preenchido precisa recarregar a página inteira.
Ainda logado, você entra num site malicioso que redireciona você, via POST, para a página "processa_transferencia.php", enviado no POST um número de conta e um valor. O n00b que fez o site verifica se você está logado. Se sim, processa a transferência. TCHAU GRANA!

### Como eu posso evitar ataques CSRF?

Entendendo o que é [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) é um bom começo, principalmente para se defender de XSS.

No caso do CSRF, o mais fácil é utilizar tokens de segurança para requisições do tipo POST. Basicamente, a página que contém o formulário para ser enviado cria um TOKEN. Quando o usuário enviar o POST deste formulário, basta verificar se o TOKEN veio junto e se ele é o que foi gerado anteriormente.

O [OWASP possui um conjunto de dicas de prevenção para esse tipo de ataque](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: O que é Token?  Sou meio que novo em programação e não sei muita coisa

Comment: @Vinicius Token é só um apelido para identificador. No caso do problema, Token é uma sequencia alfa-numérica que identifica o usuário. Vc pode pensar como os sistemas de proteção de login, como, por exemplo o Steam, onde o app do celular gera um código para ser digitado no momento do login. No caso, sua aplicação vai gerar um token escondido para ser enviado pelo formulário.

Answer (score 1):

A CSRF (do inglês *Cross-Site Request Forgery*) é um tipo de ataque que, ao executar um script malicioso no browser da vitima, acede a outro website, sem que esta se aperceba. O atacante consegue, assim, sequestrar a sessão da vitima podendo, por exemplo, fazer comentários no site, transferir valores monetários, fazer uma encomenda, etc.

A técnica mais comum para prevenir este tipo de ataque consiste em colocar um *token* através de um campo escondido no formulário. Quando o formulário é submetido é garantido que o *token* está presente e que coincide com o *token* guardado em sessão (MacIntyre, Danchilla, & Gogala, 2011).