# Devo validar dados no javascript e no php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, segurança

Tenho um arquivo que envia alguns dados para outra página com `ajax`. Estes dados em sua maioria são números, e não são armazenados em nenhum local. Apenas pego alguns dados em *inputs* e envio para o arquivo `php` com `ajax`, e depois retorno estes valores calculados para a página.

**1º)** Tenho que validar estes valores? Pois eu os válidos antes com `JS`, mas será que tenho que validar em `php`, mesmo que apenas os retornos para  a página principal?

**2º)** Imaginamos que uma pessoa acesse essa primeira página, ou a segunda diretamente com *Curl*, ou algo do tipo. Ela envia o método `post`, e retorna os valores dos cálculos. Suponhamos que ela não tenha esses cálculos, e que acesse minha página para pegá-los... Eu não gostaria que isso acontecesse, para isso, o que posso fazer para não aceitar que a pessoa enviei uma requisição direta para nenhuma das duas páginas. Ou não existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: Sobre o 2, impossível bloquear, só dá pra complicar um pouco. [Como proteger uma requisição Ajax](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134669/70) - e tem mais postagens falando do item 2 além dessa. Fica a sugestão de nas próximas perguntas não misturar dois assuntos diferentes, o que aumenta a chance de respostas boas, e aí cada resposta pode ser dada por uma pessoa que entenda separadamente de cada assunto também.

Answer (score 2):

1) Sempre valide os dados!

2) Estude mais sobre proteção [CSRF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). Se você quer impedir que robôs acessem essa sua página diretamente, então sugiro que coloque um [CAPTCHA](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA).

Answer (score 1):

Sempre valide a entrada de dados de um usuário no lado do servidor, no seu caso, com o PHP.

Não confie somente na parte client-side, com JavaScript. Essa parte é meramente visual e auxílio para navegação e usabilidade. É também importante, mas ainda assim precisa validar no servidor pois nada impede dos dados serem enviados por outros meios que não seja um web browser convencional.

Comment: Daniel, é possível bloquear o envio de robos, caso eles tentem enviar diretamente por post?

Comment: Sobre os bots, normalmente usa-se captcha. Obviamente também precisa ter "proteção básica" CSRF: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116490/o-que-%C3%A9-ataque-csrf-e-quais-danos-ele-pode-causar