# Preenchimento automatico de login e senha

Tags: javascript

Tenho alguns links que acesso frequentemente no trabalho, então eu criei uma página com todos esses links para facilitar o acesso.

Alguns desses sites eu tenho um usuário e senha para acesso. O que eu queria fazer era  clicar no link e os campos de usuário e senha serem preenchidos, talvez usando javascript.

Pensei da seguinte maneira, criar um script em js que "leia" a página e insira nos campos login e password os dados de acesso, depois eu colocaria um gatilho no atributo `<a href>` para executar esse script ao clicar no link. Mas não sei como posso fazer isso.

Não tem problema com perda de confidencialidade ou vulnerabilidade, pois a página que criei fica salva em minha máquina e só eu a uso.

Comment: Da para você criar um `boot` para inserir isso diretamente, vou montar uma resposta e posto

Comment: Esses links são todos do mesmo ambiente, do mesmo domínio local? Seria interessante um exemplo.

Comment: @DvD Não são do mesmo dominio. São sites de algumas transportadoras que usamos para realizar as entregas da empresa.

Answer (score 1):

Eu vou escrever algumas coisas aqui que podem parecer duras, ríspidas e até brutas. A intenção não é essa, então por favor, não se sinta ofendido. É para o seu bem, e para o bem daqueles que tiverem a mesma dúvida que você.

> Tenho alguns links que acesso frequentemente no trabalho, então eu criei uma página com todos esses links para facilitar o acesso.

Com o tempo e vivência você descobrirá que os favoritos do navegador são uma forma muito mais fácil e prática de se acessar rapidamente as páginas que lhe são de maior interesse.

> Alguns desses sites eu tenho um usuário e senha para acesso. O que eu queria fazer era clicar no link e os campos de usuário e senha serem preenchidos, talvez usando javascript.

Para fazer isso com você quer, você teria que injetar Javascript nessas páginas, ou executá-las em um `iFrame` para manipulá-la por fora. Ambas as formas de se conseguir isso são vetores de ataques, por isso os sites possuem mecanismos de defesa contra isso que são ativados por padrão. Se quiser se aprofundar no assunto, comece por esta pergunta:

[O que é ataque CSRF e quais danos ele pode causar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116490/1658)

E em seguida pesquise por *CORS*, *XSS* e *CSRF*, nesta ordem.

> Pensei da seguinte maneira, criar um script em js que "leia" a página e insira nos campos login e password os dados de acesso, depois eu colocaria um gatilho no atributo  para executar esse script ao clicar no link. Mas não sei como posso fazer isso.

Existe um mecanismo mais prático, que é o preenchimento automático de senhas pelo navegador. Esse recurso é habilitado por padrão. Se não estiver habilitado, você pode habilitar facilmente. Dependendo do navegador, suas senhas serão inclusive salvas na nuvem, então você poderá reaproveitar o preenchimento automático em outros computadores e dispositivos.

> Não tem problema com perda de confidencialidade ou vulnerabilidade, pois a página que criei fica salva em minha máquina e só eu a uso.

Muito pelo contrário. O armazenamento de senhas no navegador e na nuvem garante a segurança através de criptografia e de recursos nativos do sistema operacional.

Se você vai reinventar a roda e guardar senhas em uma página, direto no código fonte... Eu imagino que você não pensou em encriptá-las, certo? Basta um colega de trabalho mal intencionado descobrir que você tem esse arquivo que você terá perdido a confidencialidade dessas senhas. Bônus de senhas perdidas se o admin da rede puder acessar sua máquina remotamente. Bônus maior ainda se você mandar esse arquivo de senhas pra si mesmo por email para aproveitá-lo em outro computador, ou se o tiver guardado em um pendrive.

Não tente criar uma solução para um problema se você não tiver domínio completo do problema, ok? Mas não deixe de estudar e se aprimorar por causa disso. Eu sugiro estudar bastante segurança da informação. Você encontrará desafios maiores do que esse que você tem em mãos agora, e será divertido resolvê-los.

Comment: Olha eu entendo o seu ponto e acho válido tudo que colocou. Não conhecia as formas de ataque que falou e vou procurá-las com certeza. Mas acredito que não fui muito claro na minha questão. Esses site são acessados por todos no departamento e possuem login e senha padrão. todo mundo acessa com o mesmo usuário e senha. Outra coisa é que a quantidade de sites é muito grande, não cabe todos na parte visível da barra de favoritos. Por isso criei essa pagína html para alocar todos eles.

Comment: outro ponto, todas essas senhas já estão na minha pagina. Eu tenho uma tabela onde coloquei todos os links com o usuário e senha, para facilitar o meu acesso. Fiz isso pois frequentemente a área de T.I da empresa faz uma limpa nos perfis de todo mundo e as senhas salvas no vnavegador vão pro espaço. Pensei nisso para que não precisasse salvar as senhas de tempo em tempo.