# O que é Basic Auth?

Tags: terminologia, http, autenticação

O que é e como funciona o Basic Auth?

Em que cenários ele deve ser utilizado?

É seguro utilizá-lo atualmente, visto que já temos [OAuth e OAuth2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123777), entre outras formas de autenticação mais modernas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## O que é?

O Basic Authentication é o sistema de autenticação mais comum do protocolo HTTP. Ele é incluído no *header* da requisição HTTP dessa maneira:

```
Authorization: Basic {credenciais em base 64 no formato usuário:senha}
```

Lembre que o [Base 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) é um esquema de codificação e não criptografia. Assim sendo, você **DEVE** utilizá-lo somente com uma conexão HTTPS (TLS). O uso do Base 64 se deve ao [padrão MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME).

## Workflow

O esquema de autenticação funciona assim: o servidor responde ao cliente o código HTTP [401 (Unauthorized)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) e com um cabeçalho `WWW-Authenticate`, que dá informações de como se autenticar. O cliente manda o *request* com o *header* de autenticação, mostrado acima. Se as credenciais estiverem corretas, receberá uma resposta diferente de [403 (Forbidden)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403).

[image]

## Segurança

O Basic Auth no HTTPS (TLS) é bom, mas não é 100% seguro. Seu uso dependerá do nível de risco dos dados que estiverem transitando. Perceba que a cada requisição você estará enviando as credenciais. A autenticação pode ser permanentemente armazenada no navegador, se requerido pelo usuário (bem difícil acontecer quando se trata de RESTful APIs).

Existem várias ações a serem tomadas para aumentar a segurança do seu serviço. Não vou me alongar, porém destacar um ponto: gere chaves de API que não sejam quebradas facilmente. Dê uma olhada [nos UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

## Quando utilizar?

Só você pode analisar isso. Qual é o nível de sigilo dos dados em trânsito via HTTP? Se for alto, talvez valha a pena investir em outro esquema de autenticação.

Uma grande vantagem do Basic Auth é a simplicidade. Tanto para o cliente quanto para o servidor. Isso vai acelerar o desenvolvimento para os dois lados.

Utilizar esquemas de autenticação mais *modernos*, como OAuth e OAuth2 trazem suas vantagens, mas tem que se analisar a real necessidade.

1. **Está transportando dados sigilosos?** Talvez a sua opção não seja nem o OAuth ou OAuth2. De quanta segurança você precisa?
2. **Um esquema simples e de rápida implementação resolve seu problema?** O Basic Auth parece ser bom.
3. **Precisa de funcionalidades como autenticação por outros serviços?** O [OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201431/what-exactly-is-oauth-open-authorization) traz isso e pode ser a opção.

Vou deixar alguns links que podem ajudar na escolha:

- [APIUX: "How OAuth 2 trumps Basic Authentication?"](http://apiux.com/2013/07/10/oauth-2-trumps-basic-authentication/)
- [Software Engineering: "OAuth2 ROPC vs Basic Auth for public REST APIs"](http://OAuth2%20ROPC%20vs%20Basic%20Auth%20for%20public%20REST%20APIs?)
- [Security: "Is HTTPS and Basic Authentication secure enough for banking web services (RESTful)?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44811/is-https-and-basic-authentication-secure-enough-for-banking-webservices-restful)
- [Randall Degges: "Why I Love Basic Auth?"](https://www.rdegges.com/2015/why-i-love-basic-auth/)

Comment: muito boa a explicação

Answer (score 8):

A autenticação básica, ou em inglês **basic authentication** é um esquema de autenticação simples incorporado no protocolo HTTP.

O cliente envia solicitações HTTP com o cabeçalho de autorização **Authorization** que contém a palavra **Basic** seguida de um espaço e um nome de usuário e senha em texto plano separados por dois pontos (**:**) utilizando base64.

Por exemplo, para autorizar como demonstração o usuário `test` com senha `@55w0rd`, o cliente enviaria na requisição:

- `Authorization: Basic dGVzdDpANTV3MHJk`

Nota: Como base64 é facilmente decodificado, a autenticação básica só deve ser usada em conjunto com outros mecanismos de segurança, como HTTPS/TLS.

Em relação aos cenários de utilização, partindo de um ponto de vista mais pragmático, você deve utilizar **Basic Authentication** em aplicações pequenas onde você não precisa ter um controle de segurança tão efetivo, pois é bem mais simples de implementá-lo, porém o contrário vale para a utilização de **OAuth e OAuth2**.