# Erro de Redirect Loop em aplicação Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, back-end, devise

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação em Rails e fazendo testes via Postman, a aplicação costuma funcionar normalmente após ter logado em algum usuário, consigo testar os endpoints corretamente. Porém quando fico com o usuário logado por um certo tempo, coisa de 5 minutos as vezes, eu passo a receber esse erro de Redirect Loop:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no terminal do Rails recebo diversos erros Unauthorized:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não tenho ideia do que pode ser o problema e não consegui achar outros parecidos para tentar resolver. A aplicação utiliza Rails 6.1.3.2 e Devise 4.8.0.

Comment: Verifique qual é a rota de logout automático sua. Você deve está sendo redirecionado para uma rota que necessita de login então fica nesse loop eterno

Answer (score -3):

O devise é uma autenticação para uso em páginas no navegador, com autenticação via cookie e tendo uma sessão persistente no servidor. Para as API's o ideal é que vc. utilize uma outra forma de autenticação que a gente chama de stateless (onde o servidor não guarda sessão do seu lado, ele valida toda vez a cada request) como `basic_auth`, informar um header com uma `API_KEY` e lidar de forma manual.

Na wiki do devise ele até fala que consegue suportar [algo via API](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#rails-api-mode), porém não conheço muito. Vale olhar.

Contudo deixo uma sugestão de você tenta usar uma autenticação diferente para sua API usando um [JWT](https://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/json-web-token-conhecendo-o-jwt-na-teoria-e-na-pratica), ou até mesmo um [basic-auth](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254503/o-que-%C3%A9-basic-auth), ou um header específico com [API_KEY](https://www.luiztools.com.br/post/autenticacao-de-webapi-com-api-key/). Todos são formatos conhecidos de autenticação via API.